# How to determine the quality of an image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am working on iris recognition and for pre-processing I have to check if the image is

1. defocused
2. in motion

Can you help how to find if the image falls in above category?

I am using Matlab 2010b and all the images are grayscale  480x240 containing eyes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to measure blur? I assume by "in motion" you mean motion blur, so check out: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24676-image-blur-metric

Never used it myself but maybe it will help.